# Windows Phone 8 Access Favorites

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a bookmarking application for wp8.

Is there any way to access favorited websites in WP8? Then I can sync with my application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to achieve this in the Windows Phone 8 SDK.